# What is the rationale for this undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

> Warning[...]: undefined behavior: the order of volatile accesses is undefined in this statement x.cpp xxx

Why this line is undefined behavior?

```
  case 2:
    Vdda = 3.3 * (*VREFINT_CAL) / ADC_DR->DATA;
```

Where the declarations/initializations are:

```
volatile short const *VREFINT_CAL = (short *) 0x1FFFF7BA;
```

and

```
volatile STRUCT_ADC_DR *ADC_DR = (STRUCT_ADC_DR*) 0x40012440;
```

defined by:

```
typedef struct
{
  unsigned DATA         : 16;
  unsigned              : 16;
} STRUCT_ADC_DR;
```

Is it because the compiler isn't sure about the volatile elements could act diferent in the order they get accessed? (What is the case)

But shouldn't it be ensured that the calculation gets performed from left to right as the operators have the same priority?

Comment: Are you sure you know what `volatile` does? And why there are hardcoded addresses in your code?

Comment: I think this should be rephrased as "why does the standard explicitly mark this as undefined behaviour / what's the rationale for it ...", otherwise you'll just get "the standard says so" from a lot of people.

Comment: The evaluation order of the operands is unspecified.

Comment: @deviantfan: At least in C I do and I would bet it is just inherited from it by c++. And why there are hard coded addresses? because it is an embedded system.

Comment: @deviantfan I believe that he can be working with embedded systems, thus the hard codded address.

Comment: @molbdnilo So, what's the solution? Store the value of both volatiles to local variables first?

Comment: http://supp.iar.com/Support/?Note=99411

Comment: @molbdnilo: your point, wasnt thinking about that. I was assuming the evaluation order of multiplication - devision is relevant without checking gor that. You can post it as answer, thanks.

Comment: Edit: thanks
_@Zaibis I think you tagged the wrong guy, shouldnt it be KABoissonneault?_

Comment: @KABoissonneault: I would suggest even paranthesing would do it. But yours would be a solution aswell. I'll try paranthesing it helps. (It isn't 0o)

Comment: The compiler is right at issuing that warning, though the text is not entirely correct: the order of evaluation of the operands (in this case) is *unspecified* **not** undefined.

Comment: Also beware of this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Volatiles.html

Comment: @OMGtechy: Do the standards for C or C++ regard that as Undefined Behavior, or merely allow the compiler to issue any reasonable sequence of writes and reads, with whatever consequences that sequence may produce?

Comment: @supercat: I looked it up by my self already, the point is the sequence it self is of course no undefined behavior. but it is undefined behavior to acces multiple volatile's within 1 sequence. And that is explcitly states UB by the standard.

Comment: @Zaibis: Does the Standard say anything about accessing volatile variables of non-primitive types (especially bitfields?) or types larger than `int`?  Given `extern struct {a:8; b:16; c:8;} volatile foo; extern volatile long long ll;`, the statements `b=0x1234;` and `ll++;` will likely require more than one memory access.  Would that make them UB, since there are many ways compilers could interpret them?  Is there any way (without UB) to indicate to a compiler that it should consider itself free to optimize a set of volatile memory operations into whatever sequence would be most efficient?

Comment: @Zaibis: Note 7 of section 7.1.6.1 of the 2014-11-19 version of the C++ standard suggests its volatile semantics are intended to mirror C; I couldn't find anything in either standard to suggest that accessing *unrelated* volatile variables between sequence points would trigger UB, though numerous things note that the exact hardware meaning of volatile accesses is Implementation-Defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`volatile` implies to the compiler that you are reading something that is not an ordinary memory address, like an I/O port. For two such reads, it is very likely that you will want those reads to happen in a certain order.

In both C and C++, the evaluation order of operands is not defined. If it helps you, think of the division as a function call:

```
Vdda = 3.3 * divide(*VREFINT_CAL, ADC_DR->DATA);
```

The point is now, that for `volatile`, where it's likely that the order is important, you might not want to leave this decision to the compiler. So it warns about it.

To get rid of the warning, simply make the order explicit by introducing additional sequence points to your code. For instance:

```
short const x = *VREFINT_CAL;
unsigned const y = ADC_DR->DATA;
Vdda = 3.3 * x / y;
```

Comment: You are so right. I could get big trouble when DATA gets accessed before VREFINT_CAL as it causes to reset the value.

Comment: @Zaibis Glad to hear that the warning actually helps you catch a bug in this case.

Comment: @Zaibis Indeed, the link Alf reported tells you exactly that, when replying to the question "Is it a problem?": it depends on your data and how your applications handles it. The compiler is saying that it *may* cause problems as its job is far from anything beyond that.

Comment: @black I have for my self set a 0 warning tollerance so it at least would be a problem for my conscience. But in this case it was even more. So thanks for help and also thanks Alf for the source.

Answer (score 4):

To understand this you have to know the difference between *order of evaluation* and *precedence*.

Take your expression, for example:

```
Vdda = 3.3 * (*VREFINT_CAL) / ADC_DR->DATA;
```

Precedence (and parentheses) determines how the abstract syntax tree (AST) is built. The result would be something like this:

```
=
  Vdda
  *
    3.3
    /
      *
        VREFINT_CAL
      ->
        ADC_DR
        DATA
```

The order of evaluation is determined by the existence of sequence points. And your code has only one sequence point, at the end of the expression (`;`).

So the order of evaluation of any subexpression is unspecified. That is, the compiler can make any intermediate calculation and memory access in any order it sees fit. Some people like to think that subexpressions are evaluated from left to right, but that's not how the language works.

Normally it will not make any difference, but two of your subexpressions are `volatile` (`*VREFINT_CAL` and `ADC_DR->DATA`) so the order matters. Maybe it does not matter to you, but it certainly matters to the compiler.

To solve the issue use some temporary, just to add a intermediate sequence point:

```
short a = *VREFINT_CAL;
unsigned b = ADC_DR->DATA;
Vdda = 3.3 * a / b;
```

Comment: @Zaibis: Well, yes. But you still need a local variable: `short a; a = *VREFINT_CAL, b = ADC_DR->DATA, Vdda = 3.3 * a / ...;`. If you try to do: `Vdda = 3.3 * (0, *VREFINT_CAL) / ...;` this won't work.